# awk / sed find a line and phrase it for replace

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file like this

```
text
another line
<script src="https://link/user/id/text.js></script>
text
```

I want to find the lines starting with `<script src` and phase the URL. I just need to extract the user and id and then the whole line will be replaced with the following format.

```
[[ Link is here - user || id ]]
```

I know how to replace the whole line but the challenging part for me is how do I phrase it to extract the user and id from that find line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E '/^<script src/s~.*/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/[[:alnum:]]+\.js.*~[[ Link is here - \1 || \2 ]]~' input_file
text
another line
[[ Link is here - user || id ]]
text
```

`/^<script src/` - Match lines that start with `<script src`

`s~` - Change the delimiter for the substitution so it does not conflict with the default delimiter

`.*/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/[[:alnum:]]+\.js.*` - Match everything up to the third to last forward slash, capture within the parenthesis capture group1 up to the next forward slash `[^/]*`, repeat with capture group 2 followed by one or more alphanumeric characters, a period `.` and `js`. Exclude everything else not captured within the parenthesis.

`[[ Link is here - \1 || \2 ]]~` - Return the capture groups with back reference `\1` and `\2`

Comment: Thanks it worked. But I would like to understand the syntax, can you please show some lights on this?

Comment: @TheDataGuy Please check edit